# What is the equivalent of the Objective-C 'tag' property in Java ?

Tags: java, objective-c, equivalent

So I have two JSliders each of which invokes the stateChanged() method and I want to figure out which of the sliders invokes it.

In Objective-C, I used to use the tag property to differentiate which is which. Is there such an equivalent in Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no Java guy, but I believe `setName()` and `getName()` could be used for this. Perhaps double-check that these aren't used internally.

[java.awt.Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

Tags are not normally used when determining the source component. You could use `ChangeEvent.getSource()` derived from the [EventObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
   JSlider source = (JSlider)event.getSource();
   ...
```

Comment: yep i already use "(JSlider)event.getSource();" to get the callee of method of the stateChanged method, however what i want is to know which Slider ( 'A' or 'B' ) called it and deal with each differently. Hope I made sense :)